# Visual studio 2017 not displaying .axml file when i type Resource.Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I am trying to display an android layout that i just created inside folder Resource.Layout and when i am trying to access to it in method SetContentView inside of OnCreate method of an activity, code completion is not displaying the mentioned layout.

What i am doing wrong?

P.D. I am new to Xamarin Android.

[LayoutFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SNv8.png)
[OnCreate Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJMj8.png)

Comment: Post an image of `Resource` file and `OnCreate` method code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Yupi, I managed to get it going by myself. Reading the AboutResources.txt i found the following:

"In order to get the build system to recognize Android resources, set the build action to "AndroidResource".  The native Android APIs do not operate directly with filenames, but instead operate on resource IDs.  When you compile an Android application that uses resources, the build system will package the resources for distribution and generate a class called "Resource" that contains the tokens for each one of the resources included."

I had not compiled the project because I was getting an error while trying to access LinearLayoutExample.axml and VS still did not recognize this resource. Once the project was compiled, I was able to access the resource and that's it!